# buck build failed by constant expression required error

Tags: android, gradle, lint, buck

I am trying to convert my Android Gradle project into Buck by using okbuck. However when I build the project, a lot of constant expression required errors break the building process. I understand I could replace the "switch" statement with "if" to fix the errors. Are there any other ways to force Buck to ignore the constant expression check? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert this to if/else blocks [(Documentation)](https://buckbuild.com/article/exopackage.html#refactor-r-constants)